# What is the format of /dev/input/by-path/pci-xxx-kbd output?

Tags: linux

after doing

```
$ cat /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:02.0-usb-0:2:1.0-event-kbd > ~/test_kbd
```

as root, I got a bunch of binary codes (which was expected).  Now, I wanted to know how can I interpret this binary code to figure out what key has been pressed?  What format is the output in?  and is there a reference I could look at that would tell me what key each binary code stands for?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess that they are scan codes.  [This page](http://www.computer-engineering.org/ps2keyboard/scancodes2.html) lists the make and break codes of keys used by modern keyboards.  For more information on PS/2 keyboard programming, see [Adam Chapweske's resources](http://www.computer-engineering.org/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

This file provides keyboard events (in binary format).
Use

```
evtest /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:02.0-usb-0:2:1.0-event-kbd
```

to get some information.